# rvalue references and user defined conversion

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

I am trying to figure what happens in the code below (it was inspired by `shared_ptr(unique_ptr&&)` constructor).

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {};

class B {
public:
    B(const A&) {
        cout << "ctor from A&\n";
    }
};

void f(B&&) { cout << "f(B&&)\n"; };
void f(const B&) { cout << "f(const B&)\n"; }

int main() {
    A a;
    f(a);
}
```

I am trying to understand how it works. Why is an rvalue a result of the conversion and `f(B&&)` called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function does not accept an object of type `A`. However, it does accept an object of type `B`, and `A` is convertible to `B` by virtue of the implicit converting constructor. The result of the conversion is a prvalue. The rvalue reference overload is a better match than the const lvalue reference when the argument is a prvalue.

Comment: Thank you! It took some time  for me to understand that the implicit constructor acts just like a regular one

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the call `f(a)` creates a temporary (rvalue) `B` object using the constructor of `B` that accepts an `A`. Then overload resolution kicks in to figure out which `f` is a better match.

The overload resolution rule that applies here is [over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3.2.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.best#over.ics.rank-3.2.3)

> S1 and S2 include reference bindings ([dcl.init.ref]) and neither refers to an implicit object parameter of a non-static member function declared without a ref-qualifier, and S1 binds an rvalue reference to an rvalue and S2 binds an lvalue reference

The overload that takes an rvalue reference is preferred over the overload taking an lvalue reference. (there's a similar example in the linked rule).